# Unable to produce add new inline django model button using django-nested-inline

Tags: django, django-admin, django-inlinecss

Have a look at the code-

## models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Event(models.Model):
        _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        primary_link = models.URLField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
class EventMedia(models.Model):
        event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
        description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        media = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="event_media")
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.event.name
```

and

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mainapi.models import *
from nested_inline.admin import NestedStackedInline, NestedModelAdmin

class EventMediaInline(NestedStackedInline):
        model = EventMedia
        extra = 1
class coreEventsAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
        inlines = (EventMediaInline,)

admin.site.register(Event, coreEventsAdmin)
```

Now what's happening on admin site is, I am able to see inline-block of EventMedia model on Event model but am unable to see an option to add a new inline-block of Event Media in Event model. Does anyone have any idea what may be the reason for it?

Comment: Have you recently updated the Django version? Django 1.9+ have a new admin interface, and the icons/references changed and it might not be displaying the icons correctly (in your case, the add button).. Try to do a hard refresh on your web browser, maybe the button is there but it is just not displaying the icon... it actually happened to me when I updated the Django version for the first time... it's just a silly guess, but, anyway

Comment: Yeah, same problem...